# I'm trying to create a Web Server that will service only a small number of viewers. What options does Apache provide?

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver

In need of a Web server model that services only a few clients, so which should I pick?
(a few good reasons would be helpful)

Comment: All web servers can service "a small number of viewers".  Are there any other constraints?  Please add detail to the question to prevent it being marked unanswerable.